# Slim Image Cropper получить JSON response

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, xhr

Хочу прикрутить Slim Image Cropper: http://slimimagecropper.com/ (здесь же есть и документация), он прекрасно работает, но мне нужно вернуть имя файла запрос делаю асинхронно в файле index.php, содержимое файла:

```
<link href="slim/slim.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<script src="slim/slim.kickstart.js"></script>

<div class="slim"
    data-service="server/async.php"
    <input type="file" name="slim[]"/>
</div>
```

Запрос идет к файлу async.php,
содержимое файла:

```
<?php

require_once('slim.php');

// get posted data, if something is wrong, exit
try {
    $images = Slim::getImages();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    Slim::outputJSON(SlimStatus::Failure);
    return;
}

// if no images found
if (count($images)===0) {
    Slim::outputJSON(SlimStatus::Failure);
    return;
}

// should always be one file (when posting async)
$image = $images[0];
$file = Slim::saveFile($image['output']['data'], $image['input']['name']);

// echo results
Slim::outputJSON(SlimStatus::Success, $file['name'], $file['path']);

?>
```

Файл async.php после загрузки картинки возвращает результат:

```
{"status":"success","name":"588bf6eab2408_image.png","path":"tmp\/588bf6eab2408_image.png"}
```

Как мне в файле index.php получить название картинки, путь, или статус? Ибо javascript только начал познавать)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получения `JSON` после запроса:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        try {
           var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
           console.log(json.name); // 588bf6eab2408_image.png
        } catch (e) {
           console.log('некорректный JSON');
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: работает только если вставить в slim.kickstart.js, а если в index.php, то: Uncaught ReferenceError: xhr is not defined.

Comment: `xhr` - это я написал переменную у себя - это объект `XMLHTTPRequest`, то есть я не писал вам весь запрос, а лишь только ответ на ваш вопрос, как получить `JSON` от сервера, а вот там где вы пишите `XMLHTTPRequest` - в методе `onreadystatechange ` напишите, то что я написал, а вообще, в будущем - описывайте более подробнее задачу, во избежании флуда и недопонимания. Дополните вопрос скриптами (там где вы собираете запрос) и я поправлю ответ.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vadim_pedchenko/zxw649Ln/

Comment: Вы написали, что тут работает, а не работает на index, а что вы делаете на index. Пожалуйста, во избежании флуда, Обновляйте свой вопрос и дополняйте информацию в него.

Comment: Внимательно прочитайте вопрос, там есть содержимое index.php

Comment: Прочитайте свой первый коммент - для того. чтобы работало на index, нужно  писать полноценный запрос на `index`, как сделано в `slim.kickstart.js` - иначе я просто не понимаю, чего вы ожидаете, чтобы мой кусок кода просто заработал на индекс? Почитайте про `XMLHTTPRequest` более подробно.

Comment: Ладно спасибо, вроде как разобрался с Вашей помощью, отмечу как решение) Мне просто нужно в файле index.php (собственно там я загружаю картинку на сервер), после ее загрузки в input вставить название загруженной картинки.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52644/discussion-between-vadim-pedchenko-and-and).

Answer (score -1):

1. Ваш возвращаемый JSON (`{"status":"success","name":"588bf6eab2408_image.png","path":"tmp\/588bf6eab2408_image.png"}`) в javascript коде принимаете и присваиваете какой-либо переменной, например с именем **result**.
2. Обращаетесь к нужному свойству переменной **result** и получаете его значение: `alert(result.name);`

К сожалению, чтобы помочь вам более детально, нужно смотреть именно код, а он платный.

Comment: Вы про JS код или php?

Comment: Да, про JS код.